# Creating account didn't log me in / didn't create an account

Tags: bug, login, sign-up

I've created account on Server Fault with the "Join this community" button.
It seems to be created as I see my picture and a starting 101 reputation on top.
But when I tried to upvote I got a message I need to login and where I clicked on a different question it showed me I'm not logged in.

[image]

I think it didn't even create my account since later I clicked the signup button again, it asked me with which Google account I want to create it (I've two associated with my Chrome browser).

Comment: Happened to me too, but didn't happen again after a refresh so I dismissed it as temporary glitch.

Comment: This happened to me twice in the last 24 hours in the chrome browser on different operating systems.

Comment: I [encountered the same bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272718/262767); strangely I was able to upvote a question, but not the answer. Maybe there's a timing condition too and there's a small delay before you get logged out.

Comment: Probably some sort of "race condition", though only a dev can tell for sure what's going on.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I find it really awkward that users open a bug ticket for a company, and never hear back from the company. So users need to "seduce" the employees with bounties. This is ridiculous, this is your product, it should be your interest to fix your bugs. This is not the way I handle things like that in my company. (**This is not the first time I report a bug on stack exchange and never heard back, which makes me think, why should I even bother.**)

Comment: @gdoron bugs can also stay for years, that's just how things work. Over time we get used to it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, We have bugs in our products too (and off the record I'll admit that I might be responsible for some of them), but we always get back to customers ASAP specially when they are trying to help us, not themselves. (That doesn't mean it will be fixed ASAP or at all, but it means we care)

Comment: @gdoron but I'm pretty sure your customers pay money for your products. SE is free of any cost, so in my opinion this gives them the right to not respond to users. Worth to mention, Careers bugs always get response, and guess why? Because employers do pay money. Out of total [816 Careers bugs ever reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcareers%5D+%5Bbug%5D+closed%3A0), [794 got official response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcareers%5D+%5Bbug%5D+closed%3A0+%5Bstatus-*%5D).

Comment: @ShadowWizard, though users on SE do not pay with cash, they do pay with their activity, even if they only search for answers and never contribute. SE is not a non-profit organization... I'm not bitter nor care too much, I just find it very awkward that SE behaves like fixing bugs on their network is a user problem and not the company.

Comment: I can't agree more, and wish there was something to do, but I fear there isn't.

Comment: Hm, I've faced it only once. The fix is, just create the accounts on all the stacks (I've done this for example) :)