# Able to vote on question but not answer after "joining a community"

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts

This is a rather strange bug, it's not terribly crippling, and I can only reproduce it a small number of times for obvious reasons, but here you go:

- I followed a link to a Q&A in the Hot Network Questions (to crypto.SE, if that matters).
- I found the Q&A interesting so I wanted to upvote them, but didn't have an account on crypto.SE yet. I clicked "join this community" at the top, confirmed the account creation, and was redirected to the Q&A.
- I was able to upvote the question, but when I tried to upvote an answer I was told by a little red popup "You must be logged in to upvote an answer" (or something to that effect).
- When I reloaded the page I was no longer logged in.
- I logged in again, and was then able to upvote the answer. From then on everything worked as expected.

What happened here?

Comment: This keeps happening, reported over a month ago. Hopefully at some point in the future, SE developer will take a look.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't find the duplicate. The strange thing was that I *was* able to upvote the question, but not the answer...

Comment: Yeah, the new "join this community" is still new, so bugs are expected. As for dupe no worry, it wasn't trivial to find, I just happen to remember it.

Comment: Well at least now future users will have one more chance to find the duplicate.

Comment: Hm, I couldn't repro this.